# Laravel: sync(); issue

Tags: laravel, synchronization

I have this `Brands->Models->Versions` chain of cars app and the Versions has Accessories. I'm trying to `sync()` accessories and versions on a pivot table but I got this error:

```
(1/1) BadMethodCallException
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::sync()
```

Here is the Accssories(Opcionals) Model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Opcional extends Model
{
  public function versaos(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Versao');
  }
}
```

Here's the Version Model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Versao extends Model
 {
    public function modelos(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Modelo');
    }
    public function opcionals(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Opcional');
}
}
```

The HTML part:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
        <label>De Série</label>
        <select class="custom-select select-multi but-to-but" multiple="multiple" name="series[]">
            @foreach($opcionals as $opcional)
          <option value="{{ $opcional->id }}">{{ $opcional->descricao }}</option>
            @endforeach
          </select>
          <small id="textHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Comece a digitar</small>
      </div>
```

And the store function Controller:

```
...
$versao->save();
$versao->opcionals()->sync($request->opcionals, false);
...
```

The error shows me that the array is alright, passing the values, I mean:

```
at Builder->__call('sync', array(array('77', '75', '76'), false))
in Builder.php (line 1254)
```

The pivot table schema is:

```
id, opcionals_id, versaos_id
```

Comment: sync is for many to many, not one to many relationships.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a one-to-many relationship defined on Versao::opcionals because you are using hasMany, not belongsToMany.

One-to-many relationships don't have a sync method.  Based on the other model, I'd say you have this relationship defined incorrectly.

Comment: Great! I let this pass... Change to belongsToMany on both Models and it is working just fine!

Comment: @Marcello Patto You already did that, great thanks. Let's delete comments